# Android Version Codes : new codes on older API?

Tags: android, sdk, versioning

While supporting multiple versions, we often come across codes where we check the current version with the required version.

For example, an excerpt from the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)** :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Now, if the device is running Gingerbread, I am assuming that it won't have the variable `Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` defined, which could potentially crash the application. I mean, how can an old SDK know the version names of the successors.

So shouldn't we be directly checking with the value, rather than trying to access the variable? Am I missing something here?

Comment: No crash will be there... Values will be inlined with their static values while compiling... As an example, if you are compiling above code in JellyBean environment, then the code `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)` will compiled as `if(16 >= 11)`...

Comment: Yeah, but what if I am compiling on Gingerbread ?

Comment: It won't compile and says `HONEYCOMB can not be resolved or is not a field`...

Comment: Exactly my point! So, if I build it on a JB device and run it on Gingerbread, am I supposed to get a RuntimeException?

Comment: You won't get any exception. You will not able to compile in GingerBread but once compiled, their actual values will be inlined...

Comment: Ah! Now it makes sense! Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @GopalRao : You could make that an answer and I would be more than happy to accept it! :)

Comment: It's ok friend... let the comment to be a comment and Glad to help you!!! :-)